# can we save django form data directly in django rest serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def post(self, request):           
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=form, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
               serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response({'res':'Success',status=200})
```

can we data directly into DB. I was trying to save form data into the model through serializer

Comment: Why are you using forms here?

Comment: Since data is captured through POST request also,but i was triny to use django forms.can we use it in rest?

Comment: I think you must include your utmost aim rather than what you are trying to do.

Comment: If your goal is to save the data which are sent by your post request you nromally dont need forms in here. The serializer is handling the data and validates them. Here is the [link to the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)